# How To FindOne Doccument in Array of Object MongoDb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I Have document like this.

```
{
accountId: "182092109",
documents:[{
idDocuments:"0000",
filePath :"/data/photo/1.png",
status:"EXIST"
},
{
idDocuments:"0001",
filePath :"/data/photo/2.png",
status:"EXIST"
}]
}
```

but i need document to be like

```
{
idDocuments:"0001",
filePath :"/data/photo/2.png",
status:"EXIST"
}]
}
```

is it possible ? or is this have alternative to findOne document in mongo into like that ?
Thank's in Advance

Comment: What are the exact conditions to get this result? The last item? The second item? `idDocuments == "0001"`? Anything else?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand you want to find a specific document in an array of objects.
You can use the `$elemMatch` operation within a `find()` method. To return **only matching** results.

You can try something like this:

```
db.collection.find({
    arrayOfObjects: {
        $elemMatch: {    // Finding only the ones that match
            idDocuments:"0001",
            filePath :"/data/photo/2.png",
            status:"EXIST"
        }
    }
})
```

If your `$elemMatch` returns more than 1 result, you can **limit** the `find()` method using the `$limit` operator.

```
db.collection.find({
    arrayOfObjects: {
        $elemMatch: {    // Finding only the ones that match
            idDocuments:"0001",
            filePath :"/data/photo/2.png",
            status:"EXIST"
        }
    }

}, {
    arrayOfObjects: {
        $limit: 1    // Limiting results
    }
})
```

Most of the information can be found in [MongoDB Manual](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/).

Or you can read more [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mongodb-limit-method/).